# Copy object which has a specific value

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where i need to copy the offers (without price) if the price is greater than 0 from the following json:

```
const data = [
    {
        "id": "offer1",
        "Identifier": {
            "info": "some info for offer1",
            "value": "some string for offer1"
        },
        "Price": {
            "Total": 94.30
        }
    },  
    {
        "id": "offer2",
        "Identifier": {
            "info": "some info for offer2",
            "value": "some string for offer2"
        },
        "Price": {
            "Total": 0.0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "offer3",
        "Identifier": {
            "info": "some info for offer3",
            "value": "some string for offer3"
        },
        "Price": {
            "Total": 48.50
        }
    }
];
```

I need to get all the offers where the price is > 0 and put them into another array with a specific format, the expected result should look like this:

```
const result = [
  {
    "id":"offer1",
    "reference":"offer1",
    "Identifier":{
      "info":"some info for offer1",
      "value":"some string for offer1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":"offer3",
    "reference":"offer3",
    "Identifier":{
      "info":"some info for offer3",
      "value":"some string for offer3"
    }
  }
]
```

The first step I made was to filter the initial data array to exclude offers with a Total = 0.

```
const filteredOffers = data.filter(offer => offer.Price.Total > 0);
```

What should I do next to get the expected result?
Thanks.

Comment: [`map` over the filtered data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and only return objects with the properties you want.

Comment: I think you're asking how to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) an object in one form to another form.

Comment: yes, but I have to skip the price and also I have to add the "reference" key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map new objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "offer1", Identifier: { info: "some info for offer1", value: "some string for offer1" }, Price: { Total: 94.3 } }, { id: "offer2", Identifier: { info: "some info for offer2", value: "some string for offer2" }, Price: { Total: 0 } }, { id: "offer3", Identifier: { info: "some info for offer3", value: "some string for offer3" }, Price: { Total: 48.5 } }],
    result = data
        .filter(({ Price: { Total } }) => Total > 0)
        .map(({ Price, ...o }) => ({ ...o, reference: o.id }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you want with the help of the `map` and `filter` methods, like so for example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "offer1",
    Identifier: {
      info: "some info for offer1",
      value: "some string for offer1"
    },
    Price: {
      Total: 94.3
    }
  },
  {
    id: "offer2",
    Identifier: {
      info: "some info for offer2",
      value: "some string for offer2"
    },
    Price: {
      Total: 0.0
    }
  },
  {
    id: "offer3",
    Identifier: {
      info: "some info for offer3",
      value: "some string for offer3"
    },
    Price: {
      Total: 48.5
    }
  }
];

const filtredData = data
  .filter((d) => d.Price.Total > 0)
  .map((d) => {
    return { id: d.id, reference: d.id, Identifier: d.Identifier };
  });
console.log(filtredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduce method to map over the items and only return those with a price not equal to 0.

```
 function formatOffers(data) {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const { id, Identifier, Price } = item;

    if (Price.Total === 0) {
      return acc;
    } else {
      return [...acc, { id, reference: id, Identifier, Price }];
    }
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The next step can be:-

```
const offersWithoutPrice = filteredOffers.map(offer => {
    delete offer["Price"]; 
    return offer;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your effort...

`const filteredOffers = data.filter(offer => offer.Price.Total > 0);`

you can map out the filtered into the shape likes so...

```
const newShape = filteredOffers.map(offer=>{
delete offer[price]
return offer;
})
```

Comment: `offer` will have the same reference as the object in the original array, so by deleting in this method you're also modifying the original array